# Convert string to json object giving error

Tags: java, json, org.json

I have a string which needs to be converted to `JSONObject`, I added the dependency, but I'm getting error, which I'm not able to figure out. I have the following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20220924</version>
</dependency>
```

```
String s ="{name=Alex, sex=male}";
    
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
    
System.out.println(obj.get("name"));
```

I'm getting an exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ':' after a key at line 5
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your json is valid? Code to convert string to json is valid but your string is in valid.

Comment: try this "{name:Alex, sex:male}"

Comment: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you've provided is not valid because separator colon `:` should be used a separator between a Key and a Value (*not an equals sign*).

A quote from the standard [The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-4):

> **4.  Objects**
>
> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.  A **single colon comes after each name**, separating the name
> from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
> name.  The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

You can preprocess you JSON before parsing it using [`String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char))

```
String s ="{name=Alex, sex=male}";
    
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s.replace('=', ':'));
    
System.out.println(obj.get("name"));
```

*Output:*

```
Alex
```

Also, **note** that *Org.json* (as well as some other libraries like Gson) would take care of fixing missing double quotes `"`. But it would not be the case with libraries like Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

The string you're assigning to the variable `s` is not valid JSON. Property names and properties should be separated by `:` instead of `=`, and double quotes should be used around strings and property names.

So the string in your example should be like this (with `\` being used to escape the quote characters within the string quotes):

```java
String s = "{\"name\":\"Alex\",\"sex\":\"male\"}";
```

Comment: Just a note - `JSONObject` can successfully parse this string even without `"` around keys and string values. But a **properly** formatted json should  look as you described it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use : instead of =

String s = """{"name":"Alex","sex":"male"}"""; (Since Java 13 preview feature)